Referencing prior rows and multiple columns in a calculation
I have a dataframe that looks like the below. You can see that, to start, the SMA column is a duplicate of the Index Value column intentionally. I'm trying to adjust the SMA column so that it will be the result of a simple calculation, something to the effect of the below, which I believe would require a loop of some kind:
for i in range(len(df)):
    df['SMA'].loc[i,"SMA"]= df['SMA'].loc[i-1,"SMA"] + df['SMA'].loc[i,"ER"] * (df['SMA'].loc[i,"Index Value"] - df['SMA'].loc[i-1,"SMA"])

In words, I'm attempting to take the current row of 'SMA' and have it be the output of the prior row of "SMA" + the current row of "ER" multiplied by the difference between the current row of "Index Value" and prior row of "SMA"
data = {
    'Date': ['9/5/2023', '9/6/2023', '9/7/2023', '9/8/2023', '9/11/2023', '9/12/2023', 
             '9/13/2023', '9/14/2023', '9/15/2023', '9/18/2023', '9/19/2023', '9/20/2023', 
             '9/21/2023', '9/22/2023', '9/25/2023', '9/26/2023', '9/27/2023', '9/28/2023', 
             '9/29/2023'],
    'Index Value': [4496.83, 4465.48, 4451.14, 4457.49, 4487.46, 4461.9, 4467.44, 
                    4505.1, 4450.32, 4453.53, 4443.95, 4402.2, 4330, 4320.06, 
                    4337.44, 4273.53, 4274.51, 4299.7, 4288.05],
    'ER': [0.15066, 0.157105, 0.218561, 0.233893, 0.233709, 0.191352, 0.090935, 
           0.398004, 0.127833, 0.062296, 0.198933, 0.382776, 0.494406, 0.541878, 
           0.44323, 0.489456, 0.466276, 0.396806, 0.52569],
    'SMA': [4496.83, 4465.48, 4451.14, 4457.49, 4487.46, 4461.9, 4467.44, 4505.1, 
            4450.32, 4453.53, 4443.95, 4402.2, 4330, 4320.06, 4337.44, 4273.53, 
            4274.51, 4299.7, 4288.05]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

In an effort to avoid a loop since I'm not great with loop construction, I've tried something like the below, which is close, but not exactly what I want.
df['SMA']=df['SMA'].shift(1) + df['ER'] * (df['Index Value'] - df['SMA'].shift(1))

The reason why it's not exactly what I want is because I want the first number of the Index Value column to match the first value of SMA, and have the formula apply only after that point (which is why it seems a loop would be necessary).
All of that being said and given the goal, can someone please advise what the best way might be to accomplish this task?

You might get better answers if you tag this question with pandas.

you should provide your expected output

First, you can simplify your existing code in two ways:

you don't need to duplicate 'Index Value' in 'SMA' as a first step, you can simply work with the values from 'Index Value';
you can use diff instead of df[col] - df[col].shift().

df["Index Value"].shift() + df["ER"] * df["Index Value"].diff()

Now to answer your question, IIUC you want to keep the first value of column 'Index Value' (i.e., 4496.83) and apply the formula only from the second row onward.
There are a few options to do that:
# 1. use `at` and exclude the first value when creating the new column
df.at[1:, "SMA"] = df["Index Value"].shift() + df["ER"] * df["Index Value"].diff()

# 2. create the column and use `at` and `iloc` to replace the first value
df["SMA"] = df["Index Value"].shift() + df["ER"] * df["Index Value"].diff()
df.at[0, "SMA"] = df.iloc[0]["Index Value"]

# 3. create the column and use `fillna` to replace the first value
df["SMA"] = df["Index Value"].shift() + df["ER"] * df["Index Value"].diff()
df["SMA"] = df["SMA"].fillna(df["Index Value"])

All will result in:
         Date  Index Value        ER          SMA
0    9/5/2023      4496.83  0.150660  4496.830000
1    9/6/2023      4465.48  0.157105  4491.904758
2    9/7/2023      4451.14  0.218561  4462.345835
3    9/8/2023      4457.49  0.233893  4452.625221
4   9/11/2023      4487.46  0.233709  4464.494259
5   9/12/2023      4461.90  0.191352  4482.569043
6   9/13/2023      4467.44  0.090935  4462.403780
7   9/14/2023      4505.10  0.398004  4482.428831
8   9/15/2023      4450.32  0.127833  4498.097308
9   9/18/2023      4453.53  0.062296  4450.519970
10  9/19/2023      4443.95  0.198933  4451.624222
11  9/20/2023      4402.20  0.382776  4427.969102
12  9/21/2023      4330.00  0.494406  4366.503887
13  9/22/2023      4320.06  0.541878  4324.613733
14  9/25/2023      4337.44  0.443230  4327.763337
15  9/26/2023      4273.53  0.489456  4306.158867
16  9/27/2023      4274.51  0.466276  4273.986950
17  9/28/2023      4299.70  0.396806  4284.505543
18  9/29/2023      4288.05  0.525690  4293.575711


Thank you, this is perfect! Really appreciate the help
